# How to distribute one array of elements over another but have the element count gradually go down?

Tags: javascript, math

I'm creating mock data for my app with fakerJS.

I have created one array of 10 000 user IDs. And 1 array of 100 000 content IDs.

I want to distribute these content IDs over the user ID array where the first one will get the most content IDs and the last user will get the least (0).

Eg.

```
const userIds = ['a', 'b', 'c', ...] // 10_000 long
const contentIds = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', ...] // 100_000 long

const result = distribute(userIds, contentIds)

result // { a: ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', ...], b: [...], z: [] }
```

The distribution should look something like this theoretically:

[image: just an example]

However, the `40` here for highest number is way too low, so imagine this being way higher for the first user ID and with 10_000 users, many of the last users could have 0 content IDs with this distribution basically.

I've been coding for 6+ years, but I think I need to start learning Mathematics to figure this one out, would appreciate any help on how to even start

Comment: for testing purpose: post `userIds` with at least 10 items and the respective  `contentIds` for them to be distributed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a logarithm decay and truncate (you can play with value_data.push formula until you find what you want)

Start and End

```
0: 90
1: 83
2: 79
3: 76
4: 74
5: 72
...
9995: 0
9996: 0
9997: 0
9998: 0
9999: 0

    <script>

        var time_data = [];
        var value_data = [];

        max = 10000;

//logarithmic decay array and truncate     
for (let i=1;i<=max;++i) {
    time_data.push(i);
    value_data.push(  Math.floor(100 -  ( (9.71672 * (1 +  Math.log(i))   )    ))  );
}

//initializer
guarda = 0;
valueGuarda = 0;

for (let index = 0; index < time_data.length; index++) {
    guarda = time_data[index] + guarda;
    valueGuarda = value_data[index] + valueGuarda;
}
    //arrays
    console.log(time_data)
    console.log(value_data)

    //calculating the summation
    let total = value_data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0); //100000

    console.log("total: " + total);

    </script>
```